# Evaluate $\frac{2a}{a^2-4} - \frac{1}{a-2}-\frac{1}{a^2+2a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Evaluate
>
> $$\dfrac{2a}{a^2-4} - \dfrac{1}{a-2}-\dfrac{1}{a^2+2a}$$

We have to see what their common term is. Therefrom, we can evaluate the simplified expression by canceling out.

$$a^2 - 4 = (a)^2 - (2)^2  = (a-2)(a+2) \tag {1}$$

$$a^2 +2a = a(a+2)\tag{2}$$

Rewriting the expression

$$\dfrac{2a}{(a-2)(a+2)} - \dfrac{1}{a-2}-\dfrac{1}{a(a+2)}$$

$$\dfrac{2a}{(a-2)(a+2)} - \dfrac{(a+2)}{(a-2)(a+2)}-\dfrac{1}{a(a+2)}$$

Factoring $\dfrac{1}{a+2}$

$$\dfrac{1}{a+2}\biggr (\dfrac{2a}{a-2} - \dfrac{a+2}{a-2}-\dfrac{1}{a}\biggr )$$

This is where I'm stuck. Could you assist me?

Regards

Comment: What exactly is the goal? To combine everything into one fraction?

Comment: @pwerth Yes, exactly.

Comment: Just compute the least common denominator of the fractions inside the parenthesis to sum them.

Comment: You're almost there, multiply the first two terms by $\frac{a}{a}$ and the last term by $\frac{a-2}{a-2}$ and then you'll have a common denominator

Comment: I got $$\frac{a-1}{a\left(a+2\right)}$$ Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{a+2}\biggr(\dfrac{2a}{a-2} - \dfrac{a+2}{a-2}-\dfrac{1}{a}\biggr)&=\dfrac{1}{a+2}\biggr (\dfrac{2a-a-2}{a-2}-\dfrac{1}{a}\biggr)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a+2}\biggr(\dfrac{a-2}{a-2}-\dfrac{1}{a}\biggr )\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a+2}\biggr(1-\dfrac{1}{a}\biggr)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{a+2}\biggr(\dfrac{a-1}{a}\biggr)\\
&=\dfrac{a-1}{a (a+2)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can write $$\frac{2a^2}{a(a-2)(a+2)}-\frac{a(a+2)}{a(a-2)(a+2)}-\frac{a-2}{a(a+2)(a-2)}$$

Comment: $\frac{2a^2}{a(a-2)(a+2)}-\frac{a(a+2)}{a(a-2)(a+2)}-\frac{a-2}{a(a+2)(a-2)}$

Answer (score 0):

Let’s simplify the first fraction.
$$\frac{2a}{a^2-4}=\frac{2a}{(a+2)(a-2)}=\frac{a+2+a-2}{(a+2)(a-2)}$$ which becomes $$\frac{a+2}{(a+2)(a-2)}+ \frac{a-2}{(a+2)(a-2)}=\frac{1}{a+2}+\frac{1}{a-2}$$ so that the entire expression is reduced to $$\frac{1}{a+2}-\frac{1}{a(a+2)}=\frac{1}{a+2}(1-\frac1a)=\frac{a-1}{a(a+2)}$$